# Get searched places by GoogleApi to fill in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, google-places, gmsplace

I'v tried GMSPlacesClient but I couldn't get results in correct format to fill'em in tableView.

after that I used Fetcher but i didnt help me.

```
extension SearchViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {
func didAutocomplete(with predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    let resultsStr = NSMutableString()
    for prediction in predictions {
        resultsStr.appendFormat("%@\n", prediction.attributedPrimaryText)
    }

     print(resultsStr as String)
}

func didFailAutocompleteWithError(_ error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

}
```

i don't know if i didn't  understand it's usage. someone maybe describes me how to use Google Places Api to search Address in textBox and then show results in tableView.

My problem is onely getting results of search?

---

fetch Part Code:

```
var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?

func placeAutocomplete(add:String) {
    fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(add)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblView.delegate = self
    tblView.dataSource = self


    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .establishment

    // Create the fetcher.
    fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: nil, filter: filter)
    fetcher?.delegate = self
}
```

---

result for search "Mex"

```
> Me{
GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x60800043db60>";
}rcado de La Boqueria, La Rambla, Barcelona, Spain{
}*
Me{
  GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 
   0x60800043db60>";
}rcado San Anton, Calle de Augusto Figueroa, Madrid, Spain{
}*
     Me{
 GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x60800043db60>";
 }nlyn Mall, Atterbury Road, Pretoria, South Africa{
}*
    Me{
   GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 
  0x60800043db60>";
}ga Mall, Bulevardul Pierre de Coubertin, Bucharest, Romania{
    }*
      Me{
  GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 
    0x60800043db60>";
    }rcado de San Ildefonso, Calle de Fuencarral, Madrid, Spain{
  }*
```

print code :

```
for q in predictions1
{
   print ( "\(q.attributedFullText)*")
}
```

Comment: Questions: 1. Do you know how to use `UITableView` fully? 2. Do you know how to get data from any API, like using Postman to test an API? 3. Did you try to understand Google's API Documentation? I'm a kind of person who's not a fan of reading but Google's documentation is easy to understand for me and is nicely written.

Comment: yea i know how to use UITableView and get data from API's/ they aren't my problems. problem is that i cant use result of fetcher, it's not related to my search

Answer (score 1):

you should use array for results instead of  let resultsStr = NSMutableString()

and populate table view with data source as array

Comment: var results  =  [GMSAutocompletePrediction]()    //array


self.results = predictions // predictions  is results from func didAutocomplete(with predictions:

Now you can show data from results array

Comment: why results aren't related to my search word

Comment: try filter    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter.noFilter  and pass it as a parameter to autocompleteQuery(

Comment: thanks, why results are in nested and partial? example is search Me it reults in my question part. how to display full statement ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak with `GMSAutocompleteFilter` filter to get desired results. Currently you are filtering results with filter type: `.establishment`, which filters/limits search results. You may consider using `.noFilter` or any other filter.

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .noFilter
```

Reference to `enum GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter`, Source: `GMSAutocompleteFilter.h`

```
public enum GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter : Int {


    /**
     * All results.
     */
    case noFilter

    /**
     * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
     */
    case geocode

    /**
     * Geocoding results with a precise address.
     */
    case address

    /**
     * Business results.
     */
    case establishment

    /**
     * Results that match the following types:
     * "locality",
     * "sublocality"
     * "postal_code",
     * "country",
     * "administrative_area_level_1",
     * "administrative_area_level_2"
     */
    case region

    /**
     * Results that match the following types:
     * "locality",
     * "administrative_area_level_3"
     */
    case city
}
```